# ScalaPB TypeMapper for custom primitive wrappers not found

Tags: protocol-buffers, scalapb

I am using

```
addSbtPlugin("com.thesamet" % "sbt-protoc" % "0.99.23")
libraryDependencies += "com.thesamet.scalapb" %% "compilerplugin" % "0.9.0-M7"
```

I have some custom primitive wrappers (we are not using google wrappers)

```proto
syntax = "proto3";

package com.github.piotrkowalczuk.ntypes;

// Int32 represents a int32 that may be nil.
message Int32 {
    int32 int32 = 1;
    bool valid = 2;
}
```

and then I would like to use the primitive wrapper message `Int32` in another message but with automatically unnesting the wrapped value in Scala case class:

```proto
syntax = "proto3";

package com.github.fpopic;

import "scalapb/scalapb.proto";
import "ntypes.proto";

message Usage {
    com.github.piotrkowalczuk.ntypes.Int32 ntype_primitive = 1 [(scalapb.field).type = "Option[Int]"];
}
```

and I created a simple `Main.scala` to specify custom `TypeMapper`

```scala
package com.github.fpopic

import com.github.piotrkowalczuk.ntypes.ntypes.Int32
import scalapb.TypeMapper

object Main {

  implicit val ntypeInt32ToInt: TypeMapper[Int32, Option[Int]] =
    TypeMapper[Int32, Option[Int]] {
      ntypeInt32: Int32 => if (ntypeInt32.valid) Some(ntypeInt32.int32) else None
    } {
      optInt: Option[Int] => Int32(optInt.getOrElse(0), valid = optInt.isDefined)
    }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    implicitly[TypeMapper[Int32, Option[Int]]]

    val u: Usage = new Usage(
      ntypePrimitive = Option(1234)
    )

  }
}
```

So would like to get in Scala `Option[Int]` instead of `Option[Int32]` or even `Option[Option[Int]]` that gets double-wrapped because every `message` gets `Option` automatically.

but I am getting error:

```
No TypeMapper found for conversion between com.github.piotrkowalczuk.ntypes.ntypes.Int32 and Option[Int].
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by setting `no_box` on this field to true, in addition to custom type of `Option[Int]`.

To make it possible for the generated code to find the implicit typemapper, you can put it in a package object for the same package as the generated code (or any of its parents)

```
package com.github

package object fpopic {
  implicit val myTypemapper = ...
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to do it at the message definition level (so once for the message, not for every usage of the message)?

Comment: You can set the type at the message level (https://github.com/scalapb/ScalaPB/blob/master/protobuf/scalapb/scalapb.proto#L108) but unfortunately you can't set no_box at the message levle. Feel free to file this as a feature request on github. PR will be welcome as well, if you are interested in working on it.